# How to query in solr with threshold filter?

Tags: solr, threshold, distinct-values

To get the response as name of the person who have greater than 2 unique mobile numbers. Here, unique mobile numbers are calculated and with mobile numbers greater than 2 should be removed from the response in the query itself. How can I write a query to return those names ?

Comment: You're going to have to give some examples of what you're looking for - are you talking  about a single document with more than two unique numbers, or are you talking about documents in the index that have two numbers that doesn't occur in other documents?

Comment: For example, if there are multiple documents with name ,mobile number and other data. There will be documents with same name and different mobile numbers also with same name and same mobile numbers multiple times. So I need to write a query to get the names along with mobile numbers who have greater than 2 unique mobile numbers. Thanks in advance.